# Why isn't this PrepareForSegue working?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Im using Xamarin and c# to write an iOS app and Im trying to pass data through a segue to another View using *PrepareForSegue*.

Here I have my *MainStoryBoard.StoryBoard* where I have set up my views and my Segues:

[image]

I have my initial view with a Register and Login button that when pressed, push to the Tab Controller using the Segue you see coming from it.

The Segue coming from the initial view controller has an identifier called *SegueToTabController*. So I use

```
this.PerformSegue ("SegueToTabController", this);
```

inside my Initial view controllers code to push to the TabController. When I do this I want to also send data with it. So I use PrepareForSegue. Here is my code:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        base.PrepareForSegue (segue, sender);

        var Controller = segue.DestinationViewController 
            as FriendsTabViewController;

        if (Controller != null) {
            //I defined UserData early in my code and 
            //I have SentData defined in the FriendsTabViewController  
            Controller.SentData = UserData;
        }
    }
```

I imagine it isn't working because the FriendsTabViewController (the first view coming out of the tab controller) isn't where the Segue is going. The Segue Im trying to pass data through is going to the Tab Bar Controller. So I wondering how I could get the data to transfer to the first actual tab instead of to the Tab Bar Controller.

Comment: In objective-c, you would use view controllers.firstObject to get a reference to the controller that's in the first tab (from the tab bar controller).

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to do this in c#?

Comment: Sure it is, but I don't know c# syntax. You should have something like var tab = segue.DestinationViewController as UITabBarController; Then, I'm not sure. Maybe    var Controller = tab.viewControllers[0] as FriendsTabViewController; I don't know if using [0] is the way to access the first element of an array in c#.

Comment: Wow thank you that worked! If your wondering what the c# syntax looks like its this 'var Tab = segue.DestinationViewController as UITabBarController;

                                            var Controller = Tab.ChildViewControllers [0] as FriendsTabViewController;'